# pygtk and multiprocessing - Constantly update textview from another process running infinite loop

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, multiprocessing

I'm building a python app with pygtk. It consists of some buttons that activate/deactivate some infinite looped processes and a textview that should keep showing whats going on inside each process. Like verbose stuff.

These processeses hasn't an end. They stop only when the user hit it's corresponding button (or close the app).

What's going wrong: I cant print stuff in the textview from these processes. Maybe because they haven't an end...

Actually the app is too big to show the whole code here. So I've made a simple and little example of what I'm doing.

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require("2.0")
import gtk
import time
import glib
from multiprocessing import Process
gtk.threads_init()

class Test(gtk.Window):
    def delete_event(self, widget, event, data=None):
        if isinstance(self.my_process, Process):
            if self.my_process.is_alive():
                self.my_process.terminate()
        gtk.main_quit()
        return False

    def __init__(self):

        gtk.Window.__init__(self)
        self.set_default_size(500, 400)
        self.set_title(u"Test")
        self.connect("delete_event", self.delete_event)

        self.mainBox = gtk.VBox(False, 5)

        self.text = gtk.TextView()
        self.text.set_wrap_mode(gtk.WRAP_WORD)
        self.button = gtk.Button("Start")

        self.add(self.mainBox)
        self.mainBox.pack_start(self.text, True, True, 0)
        self.mainBox.pack_start(self.button, False, True, 0)

        self.button.connect("clicked", self.start_clicked)

        self.show_all()

    def start_clicked(self, widget):
        self.register_data("Starting...")
        self.my_process = Process(target=self.do_something)
        self.my_process.start()

    def do_something(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            #get a list of a lot of things
            #Do stuff with each item in the list
            #show me on the gui whats going on
            glib.idle_add(self.register_data, "Yo! Here I'm")
            print "Hello, boy."

    def register_data(self, data):
        data = data + "\r\n"
        #gtk.gdk.threads_enter()
        buff = self.text.get_buffer()
        biter = buff.get_start_iter()
        buff.insert(biter, data)
        #gtk.gdk.threads_leave()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    mnc = Test()
    mnc.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)
    gtk.threads_enter()
    gtk.main()
    gtk.threads_leave()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove all `.threads_init()`, `.threads_enter()`, `.threads_leave()`. `multiprocessing` is not `threading`.

Put data you'd like to display into `multiprocessing.Queue()` in your child process:

```
def do_something(self):
    while True:
        #get a list of a lot of things
        #Do stuff with each item in the list
        #show me on the gui whats going on
        self.data_queue.put("Yo! Here I'm")
```

and poll it in GUI loop:

```
def __init__(self, ...):
    # ...
    self.data_queue = Queue()
    gobject.timeout_add(100, self.update_text)
```

where:

```
def update_text(self):
    # receive updates from the child process here
    try:
        data = self.data_queue.get_nowait()
    except Empty:
        pass # nothing at this time
    else:
        self.register_data(data)
    return True
```

To avoid polling you could write to `multiprocessing.Pipe` in your child process and setup GUI callback using `gobject.io_add_watch()`. Here's a complete code example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from multiprocessing import Pipe, Process
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import GObject, Gtk

# create GUI to show multiprocessing output
win = Gtk.Window()
win.set_default_size(640, 480)
label = Gtk.Label('process output')
win.add(label)

# start dummy infinite loop in a child process
def loop(conn):
    import itertools, sys, time
    for i in itertools.count():
        conn.send(i)
        time.sleep(0.1 - time.monotonic() % 0.1)

parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe(duplex=False)
Process(target=loop, args=[child_conn], daemon=True).start()
child_conn.close()

# read values from the child
def read_data(source, condition):
    assert parent_conn.poll()
    try:
        i = parent_conn.recv()
    except EOFError:
        return False # stop reading
    # update text
    label.set_text('Result from the child: %03d' % (i,))
    return True # continue reading
# . configure the callback
GObject.io_add_watch(parent_conn.fileno(), GObject.IO_IN, read_data)

win.connect('delete-event', Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

You can also [do it with an arbitrary subprocess (not just a python child process)](https://gist.github.com/zed/8a255e81eb87431c0e63#file-show-subprocess-output-io-watch-py).

Comment: There's a lot of wrong examples on the web (even here in StackOverflow) mixing threads and multiprocessing stuff, which have inducted me to a lot of misunderstandings. Thank you for finaly clarifying this to me.

Comment: had to change "except Empty:" to "except:" (was giving me a NameError). Also, from my original example code, had to import Queue (from multiprocessing) and gobject. I took the liberty to edit your answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Phius: You should import name Empty from Queue module. The above is just a skeleton to show a general outline e.g., you probably want to call set maxsize for the queue or call .get_nowait() in a loop until it produces Empty error.

Comment: Got it. So, please, deny my edit to your answer (new to StackOverflow, I don't know if you can do that). And thanks again.

Comment: This method also works for `from gi.repository import GTK `.

Answer (score 0):

You should use gtk.threads_enter() when you are inside a thread to every call to
gtk and close with gtk.threads_leave() after call him.
Something like:

```
def do_something(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            gtk.threads_enter()
            #get a list of a lot of things
            #Do stuff with each item in the list
            #show me on the gui whats going on
            glib.idle_add(self.register_data, "Yo! Here I'm")
            gtk.threads_leave()
            print "Hello, boy."
```

and sometimes you need to use:

```
gtk.gdk.threads_init()
gtk.gdk.threads_enter()
#code section
gtk.gdk.threads_leave()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [threaded example](http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=show&file=faq14.023.htp). But a non-threaded, non polling approach would be better, because in GTK 3, the threads_enter/threads_leave have been deprecated, so your program would be harder to port to GTK 3 + PyGObject.

In C, one would probably use [g_spawn_async_with_pipes](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Spawning-Processes.html#g-spawn-async-with-pipes). An equivalent in python would be [glib.spawn_async](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygobject/glib-functions.html#function-glib--spawn-async) I guess, and you'd use [glib.io_add_watch](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygobject/glib-functions.html#function-glib--io-add-watch) to be notified when there's data to read in the standard output.